# Server events: How to require authorized clients?

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServerEventsClient which gets notified when the server raises an event.
The Server has a working custom CredentialsAuthProvider implementation.

This is the code to start the client (I customize the urls at the server):

```
  int port = 4711;
  string baseMessagingUrl = "http://localhost:{0}/messaging".Fmt(port);
  string authorizationUrl = "http://localhost:{0}/api/auth/login".Fmt(port);

  string channel = "customer/4711";

  var client = new ServerEventsClient(baseMessagingUrl, channel);
  client.RegisterNamedReceiver<CcuEventReceiver>("ccu");

  client.ServiceClient.Post<AuthenticateResponse>(authorizationUrl, new Authenticate
  {
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = "fred",
    Password = "123",
    RememberMe = true,
  });


  client.Start();
```

At the server: before sending a message I check the subscription details via

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> subscriptionsDetails = _serverEvents.GetSubscriptionsDetails(changeEvent.CustomerId);
```

They didn't contain the expected authentication details I send during authorization, but that:

```
"userId": -6
"displayName": user6
"profileUrl": a url to githubusercontent
```

Same information within the "OnConnect" event (ServerEventsFeature).

How do I ensure that only authenticated clients are able to subscribe to events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Authenticating with `ServerEventsClient` has been [added in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/62dbd41eed05a3cdf941e27c710cb2c5468253f1) which is available in **v4.0.32+** that's [now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

### Authenticating ServerEvents Client

There are new explicit `Authenticate` and `AuthenticateAsync` API's which can be used to authenticate the ServerEvents ServiceClient which now **shares cookies** with the WebRequest that connects to the event stream, so you can now authenticate with:

```
client.Authenticate(new Authenticate {
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = "fred",
    Password = "123",
    RememberMe = true,
});

client.Start();
```

These API's are just extension methods on `ServerEventsClient` so can be easily extended if you want customized behavior:

```
public static AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(this ServerEventsClient client, 
    Authenticate request)
{
    return client.ServiceClient.Post(request);
}
```

### Limiting Server Events to Authenticated Clients Only

There's also a new `LimitToAuthenticatedUsers` option in `ServerEventsFeature` to limit access to authenticated clients only:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = true,
});
```

Which when enabled will return a `401 Unauthorized` for non-authenticated clients.

Comment: Works as advertised :-) Thank you very much!